# Unable to align paragraphs to their respective images. (3 paragraphs in a row)

Tags: css, image, css-float, text-alignment

Image that describes my situation:
[image]

How does it currently look like:
[image]

**I have an issue with aligning the text to the images, under the Express Yourself Page.

I have tried setting the paragraphs to be of the same width as each other, based on the wrapper's total width.
The Pictures were able to float left successfully; with the images side by side. However, the text which is supposed to be centrally aligned with it's respective image aren't shifting.

When I experiment with the text, it's either all the text stays at the left or it's centralised; all in a row, below each other. How am I able to shift the respective paragraphs to be side by side each other, centrally aligned to their images?**

```
<Style>

#wrapper {
width:970px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;  /* Most crucial thing to align the whole page plus margin-left */
}

#section1 img, #section2 img, #section3 img, #section4 img {
max-width:100%;
float:left;
display:block;
padding-bottom:30px;
}

#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4 {
font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:
text-align:center;
}

p.title {
width:323px;

}



hgroup {
font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
font-weight:bold;
padding-top:24px; /*To give space inbetween image and Text*/
width:323px;
}

</style>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<section id="section1">
<img src="img/showcase_project1.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project2.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project3.jpg">

    <hgroup>PAVÉ</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Illustration Design<br>Avina Tan</p>

    <hgroup>REBRANDING HAW PAR VILLA</hgroup>
    <p>Branding Design<br>Tan Chin Hwee</p>

    <hgroup>DREAMS</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Photography<br>Jessie Lam</p>
</section>

<section id="section2">
<img src="img/showcase_project4.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project5.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project6.jpg">

    <hgroup>PAPER NEVER FORGETS</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Graphic Design<br>Janelle Qua</p>

    <hgroup>‘O THAT TWISTED STORY</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Illustration Design<br>Jennifer Soon</p>

    <hgroup>HOMEBREW</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Branding Design<br>Fiona Lim</p>
</section>

<section id="section3">
<img src="img/showcase_project7.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project8.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project9.jpg">

    <hgroup>FIVE (MUSIC IN PRINT)</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Photography<br>Jonathan Liu</p>

    <hgroup>PRECIOUS</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Graphic and Editorial Design <br>Tzeng Li Syuan</p>

    <hgroup>26 HOURS</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Digital Design<br>Evelyn Chew & Rachall Tay</p>
</section>

<section id="section4">
<img src="img/showcase_project10.jpg">
    <img src="img/showcase_project11.jpg">

  <hgroup>JOY IN A CUP</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Digital Design<br>Chua Pei En & Lim Si Hui</p>

    <hgroup>AZURE AIRLINE APP</hgroup>
    <p class="title">Digital Design<br>Tulasi & Lock Phutthaphon</p>
</section>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Oh since I'm new here, I'm unable to post an image. So here's the link to a picture that describes my situation.

http://i667.photobucket.com/albums/vv40/Casandrachia/MyProblem_zps2a01da7b.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here, but to solve your problem, I'd recommend grouping each image wih its associated `<hgroup>` and `<p class="title">` by wrapping them in a `<div>` or something and then floating the wrapper.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp32mtkm/ .

The reason your version isn't working is because `<p>` tags and `<hgroup>` tags are block elements by default (this can be set explicitly with the css property `display`), which means they automatically start a new line, even if there is space for them on the previous line.  `<img>` tags are actually inline elements by default, which means they will line up next to each other.

EDIT: missed the part about centering the text.  All you have to do is put `text-align:center` on the wrapping element, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp32mtkm/1/ .

Comment: Thanks, it helped shift the text to be aligned to the respective image. However, the text aren't positioned in the center of the image. To change that, I used text-align:center; which centralises the text on the left and right images. But the text for the center image doesn't centralise. Any way to fix it? :/

Oh and my footer doesn't stay at the bottom. It blocks part of the page.

Comment: Yeah I missed the centered text part initially, sorry about that.  I added an edit to my answer with another jsfiddle with `text-align:center`.  Does that look like what you want?  Where are you putting the `text-align:center`?

Comment: RE: footer, Without seeing the code I'm just guessing, but it might work if you add `clear:both` to the footer.

Comment: The text alignment worked perfectly the way it should be. ^^
Thanks a ton. (I placed it in 2 areas: `p.title` and `hgroup`) Well on to the footer, yeah I didn't have `clear:both` in it. I placed it in, but it's still hanging somewhere in the middle of the page. I'll paste my current code for the footer.

Comment: Cool no problem.  Another guess with the footer:  When you have lots of floats like that, if you don't clear them, sometimes non-floated things get stuck in weird places.  You can look up css clear fix on google, but the easiest thing to try would be to place `overflow:hidden` on your section tags.  This will cause them to wrap around their floated children and take up space and should force the footer down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=SoAtUqbPIB
Aites, I'll check for any unnecessary floats